# Java code for reloading jqgrid

Tags: java, hibernate, jqgrid, reload

I'm using jqgrid in a web application. And all operation on jqgrid is been  performed through Java code. I’m using Hibernate MVC for this. I want to reload grid after some operation. Is there any code which I can use in my servlet to reload jqgrid???

Comment: The grid is JavaScript based, so you would need to trigger a reload request from the client side. You could have the client check back periodically or trigger the client somehow (such as via a web socket).

Comment: What operation on grid is performed through Java code? Are you composing javascript on server and sending/evaling it on the client? If that is so than yas you could trigger reload grid on the client.

Answer (score 1):

i think u cannot control the gird through servlet or something else at the server side, but jqgrid can catch the status from server through server response after a add or edit operation, so i use this way, just write a status String "success" with json in your response after a success save or update operation at server side, the code is :

```
    JsonObject status = new JsonObject();
    status.addProperty("status", "success");
    response.getWriter().write(status.toString());
```

and then, your grid will automatically reload after add or edit. And it do works with jqgrid 3.8 but im not sure it serve the purpose with 4.x